# Error when trying to access a textbox on a User Control assigned to a public variable - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created two user controls with different user interfaces. Depending on a selection the user makes, one of these interfaces will be used in my class. Since I don't know until after the user makes a selection, I cannot declare the user control ahead of time so I created a public variable to later assign the correct user control to.

The error occurs when I try to access a control (textbox) on the user control. However, if I declare the user control without assigning it to the public variable, then I don't get an error. Also, if I were to assign the user control to the public variable as its being declared then I don't get an error either. I really do need to be able to pick between the two user controls though. I don't know what to do. Am I missing something? I appreciate any help.

```
Public Class VesselData
 Public RCAVesselData 
 Public AOLVesselData 

  Public Sub New()
   If Main.UserSelectedModule = "Arrival on Location" Then
    OperatorView = New AOLVesselData 'User Control 1
   ElseIf Main.UserSelectedModule = "Running Conventional Anchors" Then
    OperatorView = New RCAVesselData 'User Control 2
   End If

   OperatorView.txtDistanceToFairlead.text = "A" 'THROWS MissingMemberException - Public member 'txtDistanceToFairlead' on type 'AOLVesselData' not found.
   Dim Test as New AOLVesselData
   Test.txtDistanceToFairlead.text = "A" 'DOES NOT THROW EXCEPTION
  End Sub
```

Comment: Go to your Visual Studio settings, under VB and turn on the `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` checkboxes.  This will let the compiler catch most of these errors for you (your code would note even compile in this case).  This is a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing a member that doesn't exist.  From the code you have posted, of the `AOLVesselData` and `RCAVesselData` classes, it looks like the `RCAVesselData` class does not have a `txtDistanceToFairlead` member.

If you have a common set of methods/properties you expect both user controls to expose, refactor them into an Interface and have both user controls implement that Interface.  That will make it easy to use them interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shared instead of Public when you declare OperatorView. And, like tcarvin said, you might want to turn "Explicit" on (project compile options) or use "Option Explicit".